# Emulating a DS4 Controller for PS4 remote play on OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, gamepad, ps4

I am using ShockEmu (https://github.com/backslash-f/ShockEmu) with PS4 remote play and tried to expand support to standard GamePads/Joysticks but I never coded in objective C nor for OS X and I am struggling to make it work.
I tried to get some clues by looking at this project (https://github.com/fyhuang/enjoy2) but still I am stuck.

My fork is here : https://github.com/MiCkSoftware/ShockEmu

Is there anything wrong with the code I added so far?
Why add_callback and input_callback methods are never called ?

Can anyone point me the right direction and kick start me ?

**Edit**
I found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved: It seems it is not possible to reuse remote play HID driver so I managed to make it work by using 2 different processes.